# Не работает textField в Sheet

Tags: objective-c, macos, mac

Добрый день. Есть модальное окно которое создается из xib файла. В нем есть textField, но проблема в том что текс в него не вводит, как быть и куда копать?

```
if (!_sheet)
   [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Sheet1" owner: self];
[NSApp beginSheet: self.sheet modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:NULL];
```

Comment: может надо еще что-то дописать, просто я уже часа 2 и инете пытаюсь найти ответ.

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос немного внятней.

Comment: Я создаю модальное окно из нового xib файла. В нем есть кнопки и текстовое поле для ввода. Кнопки работаю и отправляют события. Но вот текстовое поле не дает вводить текст. Хотя если попытаться в него вставить текст с помощью правой клавиши мыши то текст добавляется.
На одном ресурсе натолкнулся на то что у каждого окна есть документ, который и обрабатывает ввод текста (или я не правильно понял). Так вот, я не могу понять, это я что-то не так сделал и что почитать, потому что мануал на apple dev я прочитал полностью.